# Can I update just Bootstrap JS file?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a project which has some vulnerabilities due to using bootstrap 3.3.7. [See here](https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:bootstrap:20160627)

Unfortunately we can't just upgrade the project to Bootstrap v4.0.0 because it has too many changes and would be too much work to go back and fix all those.

However there is a branch which has not been merge in that does address these vulnerability issues. [This is the branch](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/26212)

I cloned the branch and replaced my current bootstrap.js files with the ones from this branch ion my project's `static` folder. This unfortunately completely broke everything I was doing that depended on. Things such as `affix`, `popover`, etc. By breaking I mean it displayed the following message:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function

or for `affix`

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).affix is not a function

I compared the `.js` files form 3.4.0 and 3.3.7, and as far as I can tell there are no major differences in those functions that would cause everything to break. The code for `popover` for example, all that was changed was the version.

My question is if perhaps I am going about this the wrong way. Is there more to do when taking care of this vulnerability? Any reason why these errors would happen? What do I need from that branch besides the `.js` files to appropriately get this working?

Edit: it should probably be noted that I am loading my jQuery plugins through [Bootstrap's customization tool](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/) with `config.json` file. Could this be the problem perhaps? If so how can I work around it to use the unreleased version?

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: Hum... That may be one of the problems. Currently I am loading the jQuery plugins from a `config.json` file and the [Bootstrap Customization tool](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/). I wonder if this in between version is not compatible with that and I'll have to manually bring in those plugins I am using?

Comment: Why not just update to 3.4?

Comment: jquery should be loaded before the bootstrap, if you are loading jquery in some other files make sure that file is loaded first. you can check the developer tool > network tab to see if jquery loaded or not

Comment: @FrankerZ as far as I know, 3.4 was never released. It just went straight to 4.0.

Comment: @user2841408 jQuery is indeed loaded before bootstrap. I can't tell for the plugins. 
Interestingly enough, I checked for my previous version and all of the `.js` files are indeed coming from the customizer I linked to. I am not quite sure how to set it up without it at this point and include all the necessary plugins.

Comment: Check out this post: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25679 (People are building straight from the dev branch).

Comment: IMHO, you cannot just update the JS (and leave the CSS the same) - v4 is a major re-write of bootstrap (not just a newer version) - perhaps see their migration guid and take it from there? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/